# Unauthorized when calling Google Firebase notification C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I trying to use Google Firebase notification for sending push notifications. But get a `WebException` that says that the remote server returns 401 unautorized. I can't find out why it doesn't work.

Anyone that knows why it doesn't work?

```
public String GETSendNotificationFromFirebaseCloud()
    {
        var result = "-1";
        var webAddr = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization:key=" + "AIzaSyD0z6ngvR_we1l************");

        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"to\": \"/topics/news\",\"data\": {\"message\": \"This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!\",}}";


            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using a valid Server Key in you `Authorization:key`? Also, please **never** disclose your Server Key to the public.

Comment: iam use same server key  and wepapi key  but dont work

Comment: I got confused. Do you mean that you've tried using both? Or are you saying that both the Server and Web API key are the same?

Comment: iam tried using both .

Comment: That's odd. Have you tried [checking the validity of your Server Key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#checkServerKey)?

Comment: For FCM, you should use the Server Key.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that you are sending the right server key.  You need the one on the Firebase Cloud Messaging Tab. There are other server keys on some of the other tabs in your Firebase Console.

I managed to get FCM running in my Google App engine application using this Google [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) which I found from another StackOverflow Answer 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646419/how-to-send-firebase-cloud-message-from-google-app-engine-app)

What will be useful for you in the Google Article is the use of curl to test your Server Key.

```
api_key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY
curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" \
    --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
    https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
    -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly I agree with @AL ... never publicly describe your API_SERVER_KEY and SENDER_ID etc.

Below are the steps to follow:

1. Go to Firebase Console such as https://console.firebase.google.com/project/yourproject
2. On the left panel Go to "Database" then go to "RULES".
3. Update the rules to these

   **"rules": {
   ".read": "true",
   ".write": "true"
   }**

Then retry again. Hope this will work :)

Comment: yes .. you can test on local host and also on the "authDomain" provided by firebase against your application.
for both environment(s) you need to update these rule(s); otherwise firebase will not allow you to read/write in to Real Time Database

Comment: thanks iam update rules but see error.iam send message topic.iam use webapikey or server key?

Comment: The Firebase Database rules doesn't affect the FCM service. The rules are only for the database security.